# Last read object is replacing all the items in the collection ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, arraylist

I Am using a collection class where i will be using an Array List to add an object details iteratively.

But problem with the below statement is: 
InvoiceList.Add(objInvoice);

Each time an objInvoice item is added iteratively the invoiceList all the innerlist items are being replaced by the last objInvoice read.

[0]-replaced by the last read objInvoice value
[1]-replaced by the last read objInvoice value

What could be the possible reason?

I have checked for any objInvoice initializations in between. But there were none. I am totally confused with this situation.

Thanks in advance

Would appreciate any help

Comment: please show some code relative to the question

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely that you are creating one objInvoice item, and adding it repeatedly to the same list. In this case, the **reference is the same each time**, so you have a list of items each of which refers to the same objInvoice.

You need to make sure that for each iteration, you make and populate **a new objInvoice item**. Then you will see each item appearing differently in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me ! ! ! I had to allocate the object dynamically which i missed somehow... :)

Comment: Could you please have a look at this issue as well ..... "Executing oracle spool command which is written as a .sql file(eg:spool.sql) from c# just like executing any oracle query using OracleCommand"

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel your question is answered, can you mark as answered? Thanks very much!